# echo message with new line in nant

Tags: nant

Does anyone know how to output a message using echo with a new line character, in the ant world i used ${line.seperator}, but i dont see any related property in Nant, nor any of the functions provided this info. I also tried the \n escape character but that was printed as it is.
An examaple is below

```
<echo message="spool \n off \n quit" file="${scripts.list}" append="true"/>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know Nant, but the XML entity for newline is usually `&#xa;`

Comment: Thanks, i was able to get it after the substitution, did not get the idea to use it even thought i knew it, however i would like to wait to see if anyone has any answers specific to Nant

Comment: that's what you get for programming in XML!

Comment: This solution is over complicated. With [the other echo syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/970076/116327), you don't need any XML code, new lines are natural.

Answer (score 11):

In NAnt 0.90, I used the environment::newline() function to put in newlines where I wanted them.  But since it's a little unwieldy to use ${environment::newline()}, I assigned it to a shortened property name that I could use throughout my script.

Unfortunately for 0.86 users, the environment::newline() function wasn't added till 0.90-alpha1.

Answer (score 6):

It will be more convienient if you use echo as shown below:

```
<echo append="true" file="${scripts.list}">
spool
off
quit
</echo>
```

Nant will maintain newlines out of the box:)

Comment: You should fix the '/' after the file attribute to '"'

Answer (score 6):

Use `${environment::newline()}`

Earlier echo used to add a newline by default on append which has been fixed in latest release. So, now this function has been introduced so you may get the environment variable for `newline` and generate log as formatted as you like.

I had to go through release notes to find it, so I thought it may save someone else some effort to have it answered here.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use newlines in the xml:

```
<echo message="Line1
Line2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also made a mistake, because in your post you wrote `line.seperator` instead of `line.separator`

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your NAnt script in Visual Studio and like to auto-format (Ctrl-E D) your XML document, you'll see that if you use the `<echo> message </echo>` form to output multiple lines, Visual Studio will auto-indent your text as well. To prevent this, you need to use an XML CDATA section, like this:

```
   <echo file="${file}"
         append="true">
     <![CDATA[
cmd1 "${arg1}"
cmd2 "${arg2}"
]]>
   </echo>
```

This will survive the auto-format process. You will still end up with a leading newline unless you start your text right after the `<![CDATA[` tag on that line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml;');       
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="strings.xml"');

//for example
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';          
echo '<!-- ********************** -->';
```

generates `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- ********************** -->`

---

With `&#xa;`  :

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml;');       
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="strings.xml"');

//for example
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>&#xa;';         
echo '<!-- ********************** -->';
```

generates `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>&#xa;<!-- ********************** -->`

---

Simply with the enter command it works:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/xml;');       
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="strings.xml"');

    //for example
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
';          
    echo '<!-- ********************** -->';
```

generates

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- ********************** -->`